# how to distinguish odd and even in a list

Tags: python

I want to ask about, How to distinguish `[4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2]` into information odd or even with python programing if / for

expected result
`even, odd, odd, odd, odd, even, even, even, even`

thanks

Comment: Please share your attempt at solving this yourself. Where are you stuck specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are a beginner you can try out this simple code**

```
a=[4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2] 
for i in a:
    if i%2==0:
        print('even',end=' ')
    else:
        print('odd',end=' ')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
even odd odd odd odd even even even even
```

**Otherwise you can use list comprehension which would make your code shorter**

```
list=[4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2] 
a=[ 'even' if i%2==0 else 'odd' for i in list]
print(a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['even', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'even']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo `%` operator:

```
input_ = [4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2]

even_or_odd = []
for i in input_:
   if i % 2 == 0:
      even_or_odd.append("even")
   else:
      even_or_odd.append("odd")
print(even_or_odd)
```

Output:

```
['even', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'even']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try a simple list comprehension, like

```py
lst = [4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2]
print([['odd', 'even'][i%2==0] for i in lst])
```

Outputs:

```
['even', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'even']
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Probably because the question stated using: `if` and `for`

Answer (score 0):

A compact way of doing it:

```
lst = [4, 1, 3, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2]

["even" if x%2==0 else "odd" for x in lst]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['even', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'even']
```